# How to restrict cloud build permission to all other buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-run, service-accounts, google-cloud-build

I created a service account for devs, so they can use the "gcloud run deploy" command. I've manage to find the correct roles: Artifact Registry Administrator and Cloud Run Admin; but there is a third permission about the storage part which I can't find the right for, "Cloud Build Service Account" or "Storage Admin" cause both give full permissions to all buckets and objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict your service account to only the default Cloud Build bucket (`<PROJECT_ID>_cloudbuild`) by going to the [bucket permissions tab and adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65529727/) a new principal (your service account) with the **Storage Admin** role.

**However,** another thing you must do is to give the service account the `storage.buckets.list` permission for the whole project, which is why you keep seeing the error.

You can verify this by running `gcloud run deploy` with `--verbosity=debug`, to see the internal error message:

```bash
"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT> does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.",
    ...
```

To give minimal permissions, you can [create a custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) with only the `storage.buckets.list` permission and assign it to your service account, which is enough to solve the problem as I verified.

Here are the permissions I ended up using for the service account (relevant [doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code#permissions_required_to_deploy)):

- Cloud Build Editor role (project-wide)
- Artifact Registry Admin role (project-wide)
- Storage Admin role (only for cloud build bucket)
- Cloud Run Admin role (project-wide)
- Service Account User role (project-wide)
- Custom role (project wide, only contains storage.buckets.list)

Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: Very very usefull, the "custom role" was the key to succses. Here are my permissions:
- Artifact Registry Administrator
- Cloud Build Editor
- Cloud Run Admin
- Custom storage buckets list
- Service Account User

Answer (score 0):

> You can enable uniform bucket-level access either when you create a new bucket, or when you explicitly enable uniform bucket-level access on an existing bucket.

Also when you switch to [Uniform IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access) access, Owner/Viewer/Editor role no longer has access to buckets. (Note that the `role/storage.admin` isn't included in this primitive role).

Another way is to remove all the IAM permission on the bucket and the project that have access to the bucket except **your** service account.

You may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access#overview) for more information regarding behavior, inheritance and consideration.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you said, but I changed it to uniform and gave Storage Object Admin permission only to this bucket and still getting the error `ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket [projectname_cloudbuild]. Please check your organization's policy or if the user has the "serviceusage.services.use" permission`

Comment: by adding permission directly on the bucket (Storage Object Admin), I'm able to manage de bucket using the gsutil command, i.e. the permission is right configured, but in the gcloud run deploy command does not work